# ERRO NA ROTA DE LOGIN

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, sqlite, react-native, react-router

olá, sou estudante de programação, e durante um projeto me deparei com um erro que nao consigo solucionar.
basicamente estou na parte de criacao de rota "login", cujo objetivo é buscar no banco de dados se um "id" existe ou nao. estou usando o INSOMNIA , enviando como JSON {"id":"7ae8303f"}, no caso o id de um usuario criado.

```
const connection = require('../database/connection');

module.exports= {
     async create(request, response) {
        const { id } = request.body;

        const ong = await connection('ongs')
            .where('id', id)
            .select('ong_id')
            .first();

        if (!ong)  {
            return response.status(400).json({ error: 'No ONG found with this ID'});
        }

        return response.json(ong);
    }
};
```

ERRO : (node:20832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling FIRST. Undefined column(s): [id] query: select `ong_id` from `ongs` where `id` = ? limit ?
    at QueryCompiler_SQLite3.toSQL (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\projetos\backend\node_modules\knex\lib\query\compiler.js:99:13)
    at Builder.toSQL (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\projetos\backend\node_modules\knex\lib\query\builder.js:72:44)
    at C:\Users\mathe\Documents\projetos\backend\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:31:36
    at C:\Users\mathe\Documents\projetos\backend\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:260:24
    at async create (C:\Users\mathe\Documents\projetos\backend\src\controllers\SessionController.js:7:21)
(node:20832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was 
not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:20832) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, essa rota seria um GET ? se sim, você deve passar o parâmetro pela rota ou por query params e não no body da requisição.

Somente **POST** e **PUT** tem body.

O **GET** e **DELETE** tem parâmetros e/ou query params.

Para tal é necessário criar a rota passando que vai receber um parâmetro, Ex:

```
routes.get('/users/:id', (request, response) => {
  const { id } = request.params;

  // Faça a query aqui 
}
```

Ai sim consegue pegar dentro da rota o parâmetro.